# ufdw_j4k2_64bit.dll not loaded

Tags: java, processing, kinect

Hello everyone for a university project I am working with the Kinect sensor to get a point cloud. to work with the Kinect I have installed the J4K library for processing, but when I run an example code I get the following message. How can I solve? thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the Kinect are you using ?

1. Kinect v1 (for xbox 360 or Windows up to 1.8) [image: kinect for xbox360]
2. Kinect V2 (for xbox one) [image: kinect for xbox one]
3. Azure Kinect [image: Azure Kinect]

Based on the error the assumption is you're planning to use Kinect v2 (for Xbox One with Windows USB adaptor). If that's the case you need to first install [Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44561). Make sure the Kinect drivers are properly installed and you can run the precompiled Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0 example applications.

What the error message isn't telling you is that ufdw_j4k2_64bit.dll is not loaded because it depends on Kinect20.dll (which it expects in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\` where the SDK installer would place it).

If you're still having issues you can try installing [Thomas Lengeling's
KinectPV2](https://github.com/ThomasLengeling/KinectPV2) library (which you can easily do via **Sketch > Import Library > Add Library > (search) Kinect v2 for Processing**. It may not have the same features as the ufdw library, but the instructions are clear and you can definitely get a point cloud.